# Logstash stopped processing because of an error: (NameError) cannot load (ext) (org.jruby.ext.openssl.OpenSSL)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, logstash

Today i was try to run logstash in **Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2** Standard and when i started my logstash instance, it gave me an error. Elasticsearch is running successfully 9200 and  I have already setup JAVA_HOME path and below you can see the Java Version.

```
C:\logstash\bin>java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_41"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_41-b04)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

C:\logstash\bin>javac -version
javac 1.8.0_41
```

And the logstash version is "logstash-7.6.1".
Below is the output snippet

```
C:\logstash> .\bin\logstash -e "input { stdin { } } output { stdout { } }" --debug
[ERROR] 2020-03-12 12:18:47.015 [main] Logstash - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logstash 
stopped processing
because of an error: (NameError) cannot load (ext) (org.jruby.ext.openssl.OpenSSL)
```

Below some configuration and please help what possibly gone wrong?

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: were you able to fix the above issue? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Remove all of your existing openjdk installations and install openjdk 8.

Reference: https://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/11107